# Setting up the source Port/IP on an TCP/IP connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I have setup a TCP/IP client/server connection that will open and close the connection every time a request is exchaged. It works perfectly; the client app opens the connection, sends the request and waits. The server application receives the request produces a response and sends it back and closes the connection. Cient and server apps do that hundreds of times.

Now I was trying to go to the next step: setup the source IP address and port.

The code was supposed to work on both Linux and Windows, so SO_BINDTODEVICE is out of question, since it is only supported on  Linux/Unix.

I tried to bind the source port and ANYADRR on the client socket. And it works... For a while. Eventually it thorws error 10038. I've read over the internet several articles but without clear answer... The selection of the source IP remains unclear.

Please, note that I also have a UNICAST and MULTICAST mode on the same library (connectionless UDP communication modes), a sender and receiver, and I was able to setup the source port/IP on the MULTICAST mode, UNICAST I didn't try yet.

Anyway, anyone know anything that could be of help? I'm using WinSock 2.2 and trying to be as much as possible platform indemendent.

Comment: Why do you need to control the source port? It's usually a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Winsock error `10038` is `WSAENOTSOCK`, which means you have a bug in your code somewhere.  You are trying to do something with a `SOCKET` handle that is not pointing at a valid socket object.  That has nothing to do with the `bind()` function itself.  Either you are calling `socket()` and not checking its result for an error, or you are trying to use a `SOCKET` handle that has already been closed by your app, or you have a memory overflow somewhere that is corrupting your `SOCKET` handle.